# SQL query to get a list of date ranges by month between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I have a table which has a column that contains dates in 'dd.mm.yyyy' format.
For example:

```
_______________________
cnt_id | cnt_date     |
-----------------------
1      | '15.01.2014' |
2      | '03.04.2014' |
3      | '10.05.2014' |
-----------------------
```

How can I get a list of date ranges between the min and max date?

For my example, correct result should be:

```
15.01.2014 - 31.01.2014
01.02.2014 - 28.02.2014
01.03.2014 - 31.03.2014
01.04.2014 - 30.04.2014
01.05.2014 - 10.05.2014
```

I'm using Oracle 11g if it does matter. 
Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are :-)

```
with w1 as
( -- Get min and max dates
  select min(to_date(t.cnt_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy')) min_date,
         max(to_date(t.cnt_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy')) max_date
  from <your_table> t
),
w2 as
( -- Get diff between them in months
  select min_date, max_date,
         to_number(to_char(max_date, 'MM'))
         - to_number(to_char(min_date, 'MM')) delta
  from w1
)
select w2.*, level,
        -- Get min date if 1st range, else 1st day of month
       case when level = 1
            then min_date
            else trunc(add_months(min_date, level - 1), 'MON')
            end rleft,
       -- Get max date if last range, else last day of month
       case when level = delta + 1
            then max_date
            else trunc(add_months(min_date, level), 'MON') - 1
            end rright
from w2
connect by level <= delta + 1 -- beware of + 1 to get ranges for all of them !
```

This gives:

```
  MIN_DATE        MAX_DATE   DELTA   LEVEL   RLEFT        RRIGHT
15-janv.-2014   10-mai-2014   4       1   15-jan-2014   31-jan-2014
15-janv.-2014   10-mai-2014   4       2   01-feb-2014   28-feb-2014
15-janv.-2014   10-mai-2014   4       3   01-mar-2014   31-mar-2014
15-janv.-2014   10-mai-2014   4       4   01-apr-2014   30-apr-2014
15-janv.-2014   10-mai-2014   4       5   01-may-2014   10-may-2014
```